# error when running ssis job from sql server agent with dynamic parameters

Tags: ssis

I have scheduled a ssis job through sql server agent which have dynamic parameters in it. When i try to run the job its throwing the below error. Please help me

Utility  Version 11.0.6020.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C)
 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Option "-prd\ /Par $Project::mailTo;Nagendra.palla@quintiles.com /Par $ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16);1 /Par $ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean);True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E " is not valid.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.

Comment: this looks invalid:  $Project::mailTo;Nagendra.palla@  I think after the mailTo should be a colin, not semi colin.  If you post what part of your package this is happeneing on exactly with the code it could be helpful

Comment: parameters are configured directly in the configuration of the job step. And its failing as soon as i start the job.

Comment: I am using the file path parameter in the package like Targetfilepath: "\\Apps\hdpftp-prd\" and in mailto as "Nagendra.palla@abc.com"

Comment: Now its throwing different error

Comment: Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.6020.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Option "-ASHCPDB01\SSQL01 /Par $Project::OutBoundDirectory;OutBound_Test\ /Par $Project::TargetFilePath;\\abc.net\enterprise\Apps\hdpftp" is not valid.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.